# innehaben vs haben/besitzen

Tags: synonym

I have read in a [DW newscast](https://www.dw.com/de/13082020-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-54548860):

> Deutschland hat derzeit den EU-Ratsvorsitz inne.

Is there any difference in meaning between "innehaben" and "haben" / "besitzen" ? Duden definitions seem very similar to me.

[besitzen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/besitzen)

> a. als Besitz haben; sein Eigen nennen

[haben](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/haben_besitzen_aufweisen_erhalten)

> 1a. (als Eigentum o. Ä.) besitzen, sein Eigen nennen

[innehaben](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/innehaben)

> 1. (eine bestimmte Position, Stellung o. Ä.) einnehmen, besitzen;

Comment: When they sound "very similar" - how is the written difference and what do you assume as difference by this?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I'm not sure what you meant with "the written difference". The three verbs are spelled differently, but that does not tell me anything about their meanings.

Comment: You wrote "Duden definitions seem very similar to me."  I expected you compared from https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/innehaben the given meaning "1. (eine bestimmte Position, Stellung o. Ä.) einnehmen, besitzen; bekleiden (2)" and "2. besitzen, über etwas verfügen" in contrast to https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/besitzen with meaning "a) als Besitz haben; sein Eigen nennen" and "b) haben". If you compared only the spelling - well, that is no def. I mean, you want to know the meaning, right? you check the meaning in dictionary, right? So why not explain the problem with found meaning?

Comment: link and quote what you found and describe your problem - that is the usual pattern that I assumed. You did so with your example, you did not with the definitions.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm OK, I understand now, after reading your last comments, that you meant "what are the similar Duden dictionary definitions of these three verbs" when you wrote "how is the written difference". Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Regardless that you have already a sufficient answer - can you please include the definition part into the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Haben*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/haben) is the broadest term when you talk about *having* something. Hence, you will find various examples of usage for it. I will only give one:

> Ich *habe* ein neues Auto.
>
> <sup>(I *have [got]* a new car.)</sup>

[*Besitzen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/besitzen) emphasizes that you have something at your disposal, i.e., you *own* or *possess* something:

> Ich *besitze* zwei Autos.
>
> <sup>(I *own* two cars.)</sup>

[*Innehaben*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/innehaben) is a higher-register term used when someone holds an office or occupies a good position, for example, at university or government. Used with things other than these, *innehaben* is considered [stilted](https://www.dwds.de/wb/innehaben#d-1-2):

> Er *hat* zurzeit den Chefposten *inne*.
>
> <sup>(He currently *holds* the chief position.)</sup>
>
> Ich *habe* eine Wohnung *inne*. *(rather stilted)*
>
> <sup>(I *own* an appartment/ flat.)</sup>

---

Since it was asked for in the comments, I would also like to address the phrase [*über etwas verfügen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verf%C3%BCgen). More than *besitzen*, it emphasizes your influence and power of disposition over something. I am not sure what the best English equivalent would be or if you would need more words to express the emphasis in English:

> Ich *verfüge über* wichtige Kontakte.
>
> <sup>(I *have/ dispose of* important contacts.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you meant "own" instead of "owe" in the description of "besitzen", in the translation of the corresponding example to English and in the last example. In addition, I'd translate "Chefposten" as "chief position".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista, o, of course. I corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: This is an old answer but do you think you can throw in verfugen uber in the answer as well? I was curious about haben/besitzen/verfugen uber. Now I know about besitzen thanks to you :)

Comment: @C.Koca, done! :-)

Answer (score -2):

*Innehaben* means to hold or occupy an office and you can see that in your example

```
Deutschland hat derzeit den EU-Ratvorsitz inne 
Germany holds currently the EU Council presidency
```

and from this sense, it will also mean to posses sth. (besitzen, über etw. verfügen) physically like saying

> Ich habe das Apartment inne
> I own the apartment

or figuratively (etw. beherrschen, verstehen etc.) like saying

> Ich habe die französische Sprache innegehabt
> I mastered the french language

The last two examples appear more in literary writings rather than the colloquial language most of the time you will hear this verb used in the sense of holding an official position.
There is a book called *Using german synonyms, Martin Durrel*
the writer classified the verbs according to their usage in literary and colloquial language so *R1* means the verb will be used in slang language
*R2* another verb with the same meaning but will be used in colloquial language
*R3* another one with also the same meaning but for literary language
he even makes subgroups like *R3,1*  for language used in newspapers and media and *R3,2* for language used in novels for example.
So you've to keep that in mind, that many verbs can share the same meaning but will only appear with such meaning in a certain level of speech.

Comment: Both german examples are wrong.

Comment: @Björn Aber _verinnerlichen_ kann man sie.

Comment: Ich hab klar gesagt, dass beides in Literatursprache auftreten und nicht umgangssprachlich gebraucht würde 
und ich verweise dich auf die folgenden Links 
[https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/innehaben]
[https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/innehaben]